# Adding To total number onClick, JqueryMobile

Tags: javascript, jquery-mobile, numbers, counter

I'm a ux student and I'm really new to javascript. For class, I'm making a mock app. My app is supposed to spend "credits" and buy them while keeping a running total. I have two problems:

Firstly, my "running total" is being recognized on one of my pages, but not the other two that have the same selector.

The HTML:

As I tried different code, I realized this was once keeping the tally, but now isn't changing at all;

```
     <div data-role="page" id="page2" data-add-back-btn="true">
       <div data-role="content" id="pg2">

       <center><span class="credits" id="txtNumber">4</span></center>
    <div data-role="button"  onclick="btnClick(1)" class="custom1">Spend</div>`
```

This one works fine (The main page):

```
    <div data-role="page" id="mainPage" class="ui-grid-a">

      <div data-role="content" id="pg1">    
       <h1 class="titles">Credits:<span class="credits" id="txtNumber">4</span></h1>
```

and this one never registered the change at all:

```
            <div data-role="page" id="buyCredits">
                <div data-role="content" id="buy">
           <h1 class="titles">Buy Credits:<span class="credits" id="txtNumber">4</span></h1>
```

the javascript for those, right before my closing header tag:

```
    var txtNumber=4;

     document.getElementById("txtNumber").innerHTML = txtNumber;
      var txtNumber=4;

    function btnClick(){
        var r=confirm("Credits are non-refundable. Are you sure you want to use one?");
      if (r==true)
        {
        txtNumber --;
      window.location.href = "#code";
       document.getElementById("txtNumber").innerHTML = txtNumber;
    return true
      }
    else
    {
     }

}
```

The "credit" number goes back to 4 after refresh on purpose, but, at least on the main page, it wont 'refresh' while navigating other pages. What did I do wrong, why will it only work on the main page, but not the page that the actual button the function is calling is on?

I even changed all of my elements to classes and changed getElementsByClassName, but it stopped working altogether.

Next, I also need a mock "buy" button. This is my html:

```
     <div data-role="button" onClick="oneCredit(1)">1 Credit</div>
            <div data-role="button" onClick="twoCredit(2)">2 Credits</div>
            <div data-role="button" onClick="fiveCredit(5)">5 Credits</div>
```

And my javascript:

```
    function oneCredit(){
         var c=confirm("Confirm credit purchase. Your account will be charged $7.00.");
    if (c==true)
      {
            txtNumber +=1;

             document.getElementById("txtNumber").innerHTML = txtNumber;
           return true 
          }
          else
          {
          }
     }
```

Again, the change only appears on the main screen, and not on the actual page the button is on. Also, the confirm prompt wont work. ):

ELI5: I want to learn how to fix it in the future.

Comment: Which version of JQM are you using?

Comment: are the first three sections of html in your question on one page or on 3 separate html files?

Comment: 1.4.2, and it's all one html file.

Comment: @aheinlein I changed my buy button to 

" function oneCredit(){
  var c=confirm("Confirm credit purchase. Your account will be charged $7.00.");
if (c==true)
  {
        txtNumber +=1;

         document.getElementById("txtNumber").innerHTML = txtNumber;
       return true 
      }
   else
   {
   }
 }"

and it now also registers on the main page, but no other page, and the confirm prompt wont work. ):

Answer (score 0):

since `getElementsByClassName`
didn't work so well, I just changed them to have individual Id's and they seem to work okay. It may not be elegant, but it all works now!

```
function btnClick(){
    var r=confirm("Credits are non-refundable. Are you sure you want to use one?");
if (r==true)
  {
  txtNumber --;
   txtNumber1 --;
    txtNumber2 --;
  window.location.href = "#code";
  document.getElementById("txtNumber").innerHTML = txtNumber;
  document.getElementById("txtNumber1").innerHTML = txtNumber;
document.getElementById("txtNumber2").innerHTML = txtNumber;


return true


  }
else
```